# Google Play Services invoke folder picker with new folder button

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I use the following IntentSender for creating a folder picker

```
final IntentSender i = Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
    .setMimeType(new String[] {DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE})
    .build(mGoogleApiClient);
```

But that picker doesn't have a "New diretory" feature (**first image**)
[image: Google Play Services picker]

If I open the Google Drive app, and press "Move to", it's picker does have a *New folder* menu item in ActionBar (**second image**)

[image: Google Drive Move To]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the "Open" file picker.  It sounds like you want to create a new folder?  In that case use the "Create" file picker.  See [newCreateFileActivityBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#newCreateFileActivityBuilder%28%29)

Comment: I want to display a folder picker, with "New folder" button, in case user wants to pick newly created folder. CreateFileActivityBuilder, as  I understand is a little different. It can't receive a mimetype to filter out just folders, and needs initial Contents set.

Comment: Ah, there currently isn't an option to create or open.  I'll record it as a feature request. You can programmatically create new folders, so you could do something hacky as a workaround, but probably not something as nice as you want.

Comment: yeap, currently I'm creating the default directory in drive root if nothing is chosen.